# PHP date format from a date format like "23 Nov, 2015 16:44:26 GMT"

Tags: php, date, date-format

I am doing scraping and I got a date like `23 Nov, 2015 16:44:26 GMT`. I would like to convert it to `Y-m-d H:i:s` so that I can save it to database datetime field.

I tried like this:

```
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("23 Nov, 2015 16:44:26 GMT"));
```

I have also removed GMT by `preg_replace` and then

```
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("23 Nov, 2015 16:44:26"));
```

It's giving  `1970-01-01 01:00:00`

Comment: I tried like this. **echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("23 Nov, 2015 16:44:26 GMT"));**   I have also removed GMT by preg_replace and then **echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("23 Nov, 2015 16:44:26"));** It's giving  "1970-01-01 01:00:00"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) using [DateTime::createFromFormat](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php).

For the 'GMT' part from your date, you can use 'T' in the [format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) for the Timezone abbreviation.

```
$dateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('d M, Y H:i:s T', '23 Nov, 2015 16:44:26 GMT');

echo $dateTime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Will result in:

> 2015-11-23 16:44:26

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/VphPc)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `DateTime::createFromFormat` to convert string to DateTime object.
http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<?php
$datestr = "23 Nov, 2015 16:44:26 GMT";
$datestr = str_replace(",", "", $datestr);
$dateArray = explode(" ", $datestr) ;
unset($dateArray[count($dateArray)-1]);

$newDateStr = '';
$i=0;
foreach ($dateArray as $dateArrayValue)
{

    $hyphenStr = " ";
    if($i>0 && $i != 3)
    {
       $hyphenStr = "-";  
    }

   $newDateStr .= $hyphenStr.$dateArrayValue ;
   $i++;
}
$newDateStr = trim($newDateStr);

echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($newDateStr));
?>
```

Also visit : http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Comment: Did you try this code? https://eval.in/498939

Comment: No. I have modified it.